# How to Create Asset Library with Powershell

Tags: asset-library

I want to create an Asset Library on a Publish site collection.

I saw some articles saying to use BaseTemplate == 851.
But no idea how to use it.

Here is the code I tried to create List

```
New-PnPList -Title "Contact Us Subjects" -Url "Lists/ContactUsSubjects"  -Template GenericList
```

But now I want to create a Asset Library using powershell. please help me

Comment: Is this what you are looking for you: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-asset-library-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell

Comment: I tried that. It's not working.When getting Assets library template,it return null

Comment: anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command, for pnp powershell,

```
 New-PnPList -Title "Contact Us Subjects" -Url "Lists/ContactUsSubjects"  -Template AssetLibrary
```

Without pnp and using spo powershell, use the below code,

```
function CreateSPOList {
    #All the pre required variable to connect SPO.
    $strSiteURL = "<< Site URL >>"
    $strUsrName = "<< Site User ID >>"
    $strLstTitle = "Contact Us Subjects"
    $strLstDesc = "Contact Us Subjects!!!"
    $strLstTempID = 851
    #Reading Password from end user
    $strPWD = Read-Host "Please enter the password for $($strUsrName)" -AsSecureString
    #Creating object to SPO with the provided user name and password
    $ObjSPOCredls = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($strUsrName, $strPWD)
    # Creating client context object with the provided user name and password
    $ObjContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($strSiteURL)
    $ObjContext.credentials = $ObjSPOCredls
    #create asset library with the list template ID 851. (Asset library template)
    $ObjLstLoanDet = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
    $ObjLstLoanDet.title = $strLstTitle
    $ObjLstLoanDet.description = $strLstDesc
    $ObjLstLoanDet.TemplateType = $strLstTempID
    $ObjLst = $ObjContext.web.lists.add($ObjLstLoanDet)
    $ObjContext.load($ObjLst)
    # Sending request to SPO with all the pre loaded information.
    try{
        $ObjContext.executeQuery()
        write-host "Successfully Creates List $($strLstTitle)" -foregroundcolor green
    }
    catch{
        write-host "Error :: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
    }
}
CreateSPOList
```

Comment: I tried this code,
it's showing this error
 Cannot bind parameter 'Template'. Cannot convert value "AssetLibrary" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType"

Comment: ok, then `PnPList` is referring to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType`, which doesn't have a template definition for Asset library, check here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee541191(v%3Doffice.15)

Comment: Did you try the spo powershell code?

Comment: Yes I tried that, it's showing this error
The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer
I already installed Powershell Management tool.

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997587/windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-is-not-installed-on

Comment: I already installed that tool.No idea why is that error showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104348/discussion-between-karthik-jaganathan-and-supunaravinda).